# P/Invoke not returning expected result with StringBuilder parameter for call to GetUserDefaultLocaleName()

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I am trying to get the culture name for the locale that is currently set in the regional settings control panel using [GetUserDefaultLocaleName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlocalename). However, I am not getting the expected results when I pass a StringBuilder as the parameter.

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetUserDefaultLocaleName(StringBuilder buf, int bufferLength);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    var sb = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    int cultureNameLength = NativeMethods.GetUserDefaultLocaleName(sb, nChars);
    string cultureName = sb.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(cultureName);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If I have my current culture set to "en-US", when I run the code, cultureName gets set to "e" (only the first letter of current culture), but cultureNameLength is set to 6 (which is expected for the null terminated string "en-US\0")

Why is this only returning the first letter of the culture name (I also tested other cultures and "fr-FR" returns "f")? Is there a different data structure that I can pass instead of StringBuilder to get this to successfully return the culture name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symptoms: [GetUserDefaultLocaleName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlocalename) returns a value `> 0` (successful), but the StringBuilder buffer appears to only contain 1 char.

- The [DllImport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute) attribute's [Charset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset) field default value is set to **`Charset.Ansi`**, thus platform invoke marshals strings from their managed format (Unicode) to ANSI format.
- Since the string is generated in Unicode format, the marshaled ANSI string is truncated at the first null (`\0`) char.

> *Use this field with a member of the CharSet enumeration to specify the marshaling behavior of string parameters and to specify which
>   entry-point name to invoke (the exact name given or a name ending with
>   "A" or "W"). The default enumeration member for C# and Visual Basic is
>   CharSet.Ansi and the default enumeration member for C++ is
>   CharSet.None, which is equivalent to CharSet.Ansi. In Visual Basic,
>   you use the Declare statement to specify the CharSet field.*

See also: [Specifying a Character Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/specifying-a-character-set?view=netcore-3.1)

To solve the problem, set explicitly `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`.
`CharSet = CharSet.Auto` would also solve the problem, but better not trust it, the string is generated in Unicode format. Better not let the target platform determine a different string format, it may fail.

```
internal const int LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 85;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern int GetUserDefaultLocaleName(StringBuilder buf, int bufferLength);

// [...]

var sb = new StringBuilder(LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
int locale = GetUserDefaultLocaleName(sb, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
```

Note: [`LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-name-constants) should be imported, not hard-coded to `85`, but that's what you can do in C# :)